# PFQueryTableViewController and commitEditingStyle scroll up

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, parse-platform, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I have a PFQueryTableViewController with food information. When I scroll to the bottom of the table and swipe left (which calls commitEditingStyle), the table scrolls up so I don't see the cell I'm trying to delete anymore. If you have any ideas about what's happening I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewwillBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}
```

Solved the problem.